# PHP code polisher - exists anywhere?

Tags: php

Could you please recommend some software that will do PHP code polishing according to pre-defined formatting rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [**Polystyle**](http://www.polystyle.com/). It's quite nice and has very customizable rules. Costs $15, trial version is available. Is worth the money.

There are free ones around as well. I think there is a good formatter in some Eclipse PHP package (I forgot the name) and there is the on-line [**PHP Beautifier**](http://www.phpformatter.com/) service (that one doesn't have any formatting rules, though).

Comment: Do you know the name of the tool? I'll be happy to add it.

Comment: Afaik, it is Eclipse's Java formatter ported to PHP. It's internal, not some external tool wrapped into Eclipse. So nothing you could use outside Eclipse or Zend Studio.

Comment: I found PHP_Beautifier, and it looks as a professional tool for the task explained above. But it's not supported actively now, as I see...

Answer (score 1):

I use codesniffer (http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) to check my code and keep it nice and tidy.  It doesn't do any re-formatting tho, just displays a list of errors based on whichever standard you choose to check against then you go fix them by hand.  Personally I prefer that tho.  Its also very flexible and you can add your own standards or amend the existing ones using php